# Hide scrollbar buttons independantly

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I have created a custom template for the scrollbar (horizontal) which contains now just the two scroll buttons without the scrollbar, both of which are in a separate grid column. I want the right button to disappear when we can no longer scroll to the right and vice versa for the left button. 
I can set the scrollbar visibility in the scrollviewer template to:

Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"

Which will only show the scrollbar when necessary but don’t see any property within the scrollbar that would expose when the scrollbar has reached its rightmost or leftmost position that I could bind the visibility property to…
Not sure really how to go about this one so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this...

```
<MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter" />

<Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollViewerStyle"
      TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
           <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                 <ColumnDefinition />
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
              <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
                            CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=.}">
                 <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="0"
                                  FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                       <Binding Path="ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="HorizontalOffset"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="ExtentWidth"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="ViewportWidth"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                 </RepeatButton.Visibility>
              </RepeatButton>
              <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2"
                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
                            CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=.}">
                 <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="100"
                                  FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                       <Binding Path="ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="HorizontalOffset"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="ExtentWidth"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                       <Binding Path="ViewportWidth"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                 </RepeatButton.Visibility>
              </RepeatButton>
           </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling in WPF is taken care of by the [`IScrollInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Its `LineLeft()`, `LineRight()`, `PageLeft()` and `PageRight()` methods do the actual content scrolling and are executed by the various `RepeatButton`s in the `ScrollBar ControlTemplate`. It also provides the `HorizontalOffset`, `ViewportWidth` and `ExtentWidth` properties that you can use to determine where the scrolled content is. These methods and properties are exposed on the `ScrollViewer` class.

While I haven't tried this, I believe that you can detect when the content is scrolled to the far right like this:

```
bool isAtRightSide = HorizontalOffset >= ExtentWidth - ViewportWidth;
```

The `HorizontalOffset` property *gets the horizontal offset of the scrolled content*.
The `ExtentWidth` property *gets the horizontal size of the extent.* (Total size)
The `ViewportWidth` property *gets the horizontal size of the viewport for this content.*

Comment: The problem is I have no code behind as I am tying to create a framework control, everything is defined entirely in XAML.

Comment: In short, you can't do this in pure XAML. Furthermore, if that was your requirement, then you should have put that in your question. However, if you create a `CustomControl`, then you *can* use code with the XAML.